# Password protected pages WordPress, hiding additional areas

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a sidebar to hide on a password protected page in WordPress until after the password is entered. I have the following code but with no success.

```
<?php 

if ( !post_password_required() ) { 
echo '<style> #text-6 {
      display: none;
      }
      </style>'; 
} else {
echo '<style> #text-6 {
      display: block;
      } 
      </style>';
}

?>
```

Do I need more in my PHP?

Comment: what does return `post_password_required()` function ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer nothing changes on the page, cant even see the output of the <style> tags in the source code

Answer (score 0):

if 'post_password_required()' function checks the page is password protected then you want to hide the sidebar

```
<?php 

if (post_password_required() ) { 
echo '<style> #text-6 {
      display: none !important;
      }
      </style>'; 
} else {
echo '<style> #text-6 {
      display: block;
      } 
      </style>';
}

?>
```